# how to add angular tags to html attribute in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor

rather than do this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="AltSchedule" ng-show="someVar" />
```

i want to be able to do this

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.AltSchedule, new  {ng-show="someVar" })
```

but i can't seem to find an answer on who to accomplish using the html helpers with angular tags.  Is there way to add angular tags to the html attributes parameter for an html helper?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Underscores in the htmlAttributes parameter are converted to hyphens when the control is rendered:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.AltSchedule, new  {ng_show="someVar" })
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me 4 years after you answered.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the overload that takes a dictionary:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.AltSchedule, new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "ng-show", "someVar" } })
```